# JDBC Stored Procedure Call IN Parameter Table of Records

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, plsql

I want to call a stored procedure with a table of records type in java. The record contains just numbers, but I have to pass integers and decimals.

I haven't found a proper solution for my problem (Neither for OracleCallableStatement nor
StoredProcedureQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `CallableStatement`, that comes with `java.sql` package.

First of all you have to create and open the connection. For this I usually use an Sql2o instance for connecting to a specific database.

So:

```
Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPass);
Connection conn = sql2o.open();
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.getJdbcConnection().prepareCall("{call your_stored_procedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")
```

The questions marks are the number of IN/OUT arguments of your stored.
To set the arguments:

```
cstmt.setObject(1,your_value, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setObject(2, your_value, Types.DOUBLE);
... // set all your arguments
cstmt.execute();
```

if you have also out parameter in your stored you can register it with

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

The first argument of `cstmt.setObject()` is the parameter index of your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Since a recent version of ojdbc, and Oracle 18c, you can finally bind PL/SQL `TABLE OF RECORD` types just like a SQL `TABLE OF OBJECT` type, using standard JDBC API. For this, you have to implement a Java representation of your `RECORD`, which implements [`java.sql.SQLData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLData.html):

```java
class MyType implements SQLData {
    // Constructors, getters, and setters

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "P.MY_TYPE";
    }

    @Override
    public final void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName)
    throws SQLException {
        this.val1 = stream.readInt();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public final void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
    throws SQLException {
        stream.writeInt(val1);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, assuming a package like the following:

```java
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p AS
  TYPE my_type IS RECORD (i NUMBER);
  TYPE my_type_table IS TABLE OF my_type;
  FUNCTION f (i my_type_table) RETURN my_type_table;
END p;
```

you can bind this type to the JDBC API like this:

```java
try (CallableStatement s = c.prepareCall("{ ? = call p.f (?) }")) {
    Array a = c.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)
               .createARRAY("P.MY_TYPE_TABLE", new MyType[] { new MyType(1) });

    try {
        s.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "P.MY_TYPE_TABLE");
        s.setObject(2, a);
        s.execute();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList((Object[])
            s.getArray(1).getArray(Map.of("P.MY_TYPE_TABLE", MyType.class))
        ));
    }
    finally {
        a.free();
    }
}
```

It's quite laborious, but you can do it. If using a third party library is an option, [jOOQ supports a code generator that can generate all of the above metadata for you](https://blog.jooq.org/painless-access-from-java-to-plsql-procedures-with-jooq/), so your call will just be:

```java
MytypeTableRecord result = 
    P.f(configuration, new MyTypeTableRecord(new MyTypeRecord(1)));
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.